# Appending SEDF (or arrow table) to Enterprise Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, spatially-enabled-dataframe

I have a Notebook that takes a Civil 3D CAD .dwg and converts it to a spatially-enabled dataframe. I want to take that dataframe and append it to an existing feature class in an Enterprise DB.

However, I've been unable to get arcpy.management.Append() to actually work. I've also tried converting into an arrows table but the schema (seen below) doesn't match esri specifications. Append is notoriously slow so I'm wondering if there's any point to trying to use it or whether there's some other method that may work faster and more efficiently such as a search/insert cursor or something else. I'm new to working with arrow tables & have only written seDF's in the past.

While I can successfully read the target Fc, convert that to a sedf, concat the two, and overwrite--it takes about 5 minutes to do so for only 16 records. I suspect I can reduce that speed by 50% by using a different server tunnel to connect to the Enterprise DB but would still like to optimize programmatically as even 2.5minutes is long for what will, in the future, likely be thousands of records being re-written on dozens of feature classes.

What are best practices for appending data from an sedf/arrow table to an existing feature class?

```
AME: string
LENGTH: string
WIDTH: string
PVMT_DEPTH: string
PVMT_TYPE: string
DURATION: string
CLASSIFICATION: string
DETAIL_1: string
DETAIL_2: string
SPEC_SHT: string
NOTES: string
RECORD: string
SHAPE: binary
OBJECTID: int64
DEVELOPER: string
CONTRACTOR: string
THIRD_PARTY_CLIENT: null
PROJECT_NUMBER: string
PROJECT_NAME: string
PHASE: string
REVISION: string
__index_level_0__: int64
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na' + 2784
geo: '{"primary_column": "SHAPE", "columns": {"SHAPE": {"crs": "PROJCS[\"' + 901
```

Comment: dwg to Enterprise DB? Oracle? We use an  ETL tool (server side for automating this type of work). we use etl to QA/validate dwg files before they go near the Database

Comment: SQL server instead of Oracle. What ETL tool to you use?

Comment: FME Desktop (renamed Form) and FME Server (renamed Flow)